# How to create a landing page with the child theme

Tags: wordpress, header, themes, footer, html

I have purchased MasterStudy theme for my website and It doesn't have a template with no header or footer to create a landing page. My question is: how can I create a page with such template via its child theme and use visual composer to add the content? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understood your situation, but I'll try to help anyway.

Have you checked all the Theme Options? Sometimes you can easily delete the footer and header through the Theme Options. In case you have and there's not an option to do so, the smart move would be to create a custom page to fit your needs. You'll find some information about how to do so right here http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

Remember that the visual composer only edits the content of the webpage per se, meaning, it can't modify the template structure (footer and header in this case).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, there is no option to remove the header or the footer in this theme. Creating a custom page like this way in the article is not what I exactly need. Because it creates a blank page first without being able to use visual composer on it which means I have to code to put the content on that page. I need to create a blank page with no header or footer and then use visual composer to add the content.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution is much more simple than I thought. I resolved it by adding custom CSS to hide the header and the footer of the page by mentioning Its ID. Here is the Code I used >>

```css
.page-id-2114 #header {
    display: none;
}
.page-id-2114 footer {
    display: none;
}
```